# Experience Editor removing opening paragraph tag in RTE

Tags: experience-editor, richtext-editor

We've noticed that when editing RTE fields in the experience editor of version 9.3 the first paragraph tag is being stripped.
For example:

**This (prior to save)**:

```
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test!</p>
```

**Becomes (after save)**:

```
test
<p>test</p>
<p>test!</p>
```

Anyone having the same issue, or have a fix/recommendation?

I have created a support ticket, and will update this story as well.

========================================================================

**Update from Sitecore:**

> The behavior you reported has been registered as a bug in our bug tracking system. Thank you for reporting the problem.
>
> We are currently working closely with the development team to investigate for the possible ways to resolve or work around the problem. Please give us some time to perform deeper investigation and we will get back to you as soon as possible. Note that the investigation is performed for Sitecore 9.3.
>
> To track the future status of this bug report, please use reference number 395536. More information about public reference numbers can be found here:
>
> https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/853187

Comment: Thanks - we have the same issue ;-) Looking forward to the update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the hotfix available at the following URL:
https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/hab14a1l671cly284pe15io20q0bzayz

Be aware that the hotfix was built specifically for Sitecore XP 9.3, and you should not install it on other Sitecore versions or in combination with other hotfixes, unless explicitly instructed by Sitecore Support.

Note that you need to extract ZIP file contents to locate installation instructions and related files inside it.

Unless stated differently in the installation instructions, the hotfix should be installed on CM instance and then synced with other instances using your regular development practices.

To monitor the progress of the related issue, please use reference number 395536. More information about public reference numbers can be found here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/853187

Comment: It seems I can't get that fix, with my Sitecore profile. Is there another way of getting it or should I ask Sitecore support for it ?

Comment: It would be best to get it by contacting support or having a profile created. Just in case that patch is updated or you need other patches in the future.